# Authorization required to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having difficulties right now. I am constantly getting `"Authorization required to perform that action"` everyday.

The trigger event that I am using is `onFormSubmit`. I did not edit the code at all after creating the trigger but I am getting this error everyday. When I created the trigger, Google did ask me for approval and permission to allow the trigger. Even so, it kept having this error.

May I know what is the possible cause of this?

```
 function onFormSubmit(e) {

    if (e.values && !e.values[1]) { return; }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  var stage1pressUL = sheet.getRange("AI2").getValue();
  var stage1pressLL = sheet.getRange("AJ2").getValue();

  var recipients = ""+sheet.getRange("AH2").getValues();
  var params = new Array();
  var positivelimit = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  var negativelimit = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

  for(var i=0; i<sheet.getMaxColumns(); i++){
   params[i] = e.values[i]; 
  }

  console.log(params);

  var paramsInfo = [
    {
      name: "ap2233stage1press", number: 3, min: stage1pressLL, max: stage1pressUL
    },
    {
      name: "ap2234stage1press", number: 4, min: stage1pressLL, max: stage1pressUL
    },
    {
      name: "ap2235stage1press", number: 5, min: stage1pressLL, max: stage1pressUL
    },
    {
      name: "ap2236stage1press", number: 6, min: stage1pressLL, max: stage1pressUL
    },
    ];

  for(var z=0; z<paramsInfo.length; z++){
    var paramsInfoCheck = paramsInfo[z];
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(paramsInfoCheck.name);
    template[paramsInfoCheck.name] = params[paramsInfoCheck.number];
    template.recorded = params[31];

    if((params[paramsInfoCheck.number] != "-5") && ((params[paramsInfoCheck.number] < paramsInfoCheck.min) || (params[paramsInfoCheck.number] > paramsInfoCheck.max))){

      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,
    "40K RO Parameter Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent()});
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you authorize your script from inside the script editor?  Can your share your script.

Comment: Yes I did authorized it through the script editor. Whenever I create a trigger through the event page, it request for an authorization to review the permissions. This is done almost everyday when I get a failure notification indicating that I need to authorize the code. Could it be that my recipients are consisting of a 13 individual email?

Comment: Who does the code execute as?

Comment: The owner of the spreadsheet and script created the trigger. I tried to create a trigger even when I am not the owner, still doesn't work.

Comment: Do the form, the spreadsheet, the script and the trigger have the same owner?

Comment: Yes it does. I've checked multiple times, that the form, spreadsheet, script and trigger are made from the same owner.

Comment: When you get an email with the title `Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: authorization required to perform this action` - the email contains a table and there is a column with the header `Error Message`. What is its content?

Comment: The error message is what I mentioned in my OP - ``Authorization is required to perform that action.`` Upon monitoring, I have realized that it is not issuing anymore errors. I made changes by creating Google Groups which is adding the emails that I want to send to within a group. The email that I send to now is just an email that will branch out the emails sent to the different email.

Comment: Oh, then I know what your error is, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem comes from your line

`var recipients = ""+sheet.getRange("AH2").getValues();`

### Explanation

`MailApp.sendEmail()` accepts comma separated strings as parameter for multiple recipients.

However, `getValues()` returns you a nested array instead of a string, e.g.

`[[user@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com]]`

### Solution

Replace `getValues()` by `getValue()` or (makes sense if your range contains more than one cell) by `getValues()[0][0]`. This will return

`user@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com`

without brackets.

Comment: I managed to find a simpler way to fix this multiple email issue. I have created a dummy email by using Google Group. The email consists of several recipients that I want to send to. The program will send the email to this dummy email and have it sent to the different email that I set it to send to. After monitoring for a few days, I have no authorization errors anymore. However, your answer may be a solution to it but using Google Groups have fixed my problem. On a side note, thank you.

Comment: Sure, your solution is good workaround if your list of recipients will be always the same, but if you ever want to chose the recipients dynamically from the cell contents - just remember to replace `getValues()` through `getValue()`.

Comment: Got it on that. I can add/remove through Google Groups in the case i need to change the recipients. Thanks a lot for highlighting another possible solution.